# Spotfire Bargraph to show Avg Quality by year for previous years and by month for current year

Tags: spotfire

I have a bargraph which shows the quality of my data for each month. As the data is growing over the years, the graph is getting messy. So, i would like to show Avg Quality by year for all those months in Previous years but monthly for the current year.

Can any one help me how to achieve this.

Thanks,
-Dileep

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be separated into two charts, or it just won't be legible. I'd suggest:

1. Creating an AVG by Year bar chart graph for all your data
2. Creating a details visualization of the above Yearly Average data which shows the 12 months of that year with SUM() as your aggregation method. Be sure to have YEAR > Month on your category axis

Thus, if you need to compare 1, 2, 3 or all the years by month you can select them all, or just the ones you want.

Comment: Thank you Scsimon for your quick response. I understand we can show them using 2 graphs but is there a possibility to make it a one graph either by using python or any kind of script?

Comment: @Dileep You are asking to show only years for a portion of the category axis and then years > months on another portion. This isn't available for a continual axis. However, you can create two bar charts that are independent of each other and limit the data to a specific date range, and place them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the help of some calculated columns. To help explain, let's assume the value column in your data set is called `Value` and the date column in your data set is called `ValueDate`. I created some fictional data that extends into April, 2017 to help illustrate the solution.

1. Insert a calculated column to classify whether or not the date in each row is in the current year or not. I'm going to call the column `DateGrouping`.

   `CASE WHEN Year(DateTimeNow())=Year([ValueDate]) THEN "Monthly" WHEN Year(DateTimeNow())>Year([ValueDate]) THEN "Yearly" END AS [DateGrouping]`
2. Insert a calculated column that tells us the last date of the month for `ValueDate`. E.g., if the date in the row is 4/10/2015, the last day of the month for the day in that row is 4/30/2015. If the date in the row is 7/8/2013, the last day of the month for the date in that row is 7/31/2013. We'll call this column `LastDateOfMonth`.

   `DateAdd("day",-1,date(Year([ValueDate]),Month(DateAdd("month",1,[ValueDate])),1))`
3. Insert a calculated column that tells us the last date of the *year* for `ValueDate`. Of course, it's just Dec. 31 of `ValueDate`'s year. Call this column `LastDateOfYear`.

   `Date(Year([ValueDate]),12,31)`
4. Finally, we utilize the previous three calculated columns to add a calculated column for the date value we want to plot. You are wanting to plot by month for the current year, and by year for prior years.

   `CASE [DateGrouping] WHEN "Monthly" THEN [LastDayOfMonth] WHEN "Yearly" THEN [LastDateOfYear] END`

On my value axis is the `Value` column, which I'm aggregating as an Average. On my category axis is the calculated `DatePlot` column -- I set the category axis to Categorical Scale. And I'm coloring by the calculated `DateGrouping` column to offer a visual cue that the data is aggregated differently over time.

[image: Sample Bar Chart]

Now, *should* this be done? There are certainly some pitfalls. You can't make the category axis Continuous Scale or else you'll see all the empty months when we're lumping prior years into Dec. 31. On the other hand, gaps are good visually when there is no data for a given period. So I don't know. But I pictured what you were asking and decided to try it. Buyer beware!